# Angular project doesn't know click, button, ngIf/ngFor

Tags: angular, angular12, angular13

[I use angular v13 and node js v12.22 in my project. This problem suddenly come, I just close several hour and open it again after that I found this similar errors in all components. My project doesn't know 'click', 'button', 'ngFor/ngIf/etc ..' like the ss, anyone know what happen with this? And how to solve it? Because I already try to create new project and still the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4npg.png)

Comment: Can you try to run ng serve from a command line in the folder where you client app is installed and paste any errors here? Thinking you have a compilation error, likely in a code change you made recently.

Comment: Oh my I confused right now. I found uniqe case, i was doing what you suggest and i'm shock it successfull with other portal. But in otheer side I try again to run from vs code, the errors still showed so that I cant running the program.

Comment: @student Could you share the console error output? That will help to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What folder do you have open in VS Code?  Is it the root of the project?  Try opening the angular project in VS Code, not the whole project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty hard to tell whats wrong from only that screenshot. The best would be to post an example Git repo so we can check out your complete code.

But the first thing that comes to my mind is that you maybe forgot to `import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';`

Comment: you app might have stopped, check your terminal..

Comment: That would explain ngFor not working, but not a click event.

Comment: sorry that's my bad. Here is the github https://github.com/VinandaKristianti/sipekerti_sp I work on.

Comment: @student it works perfectly fine for me. I used node 12.22 as well and just ran `npm clean-install` and `npm start`. Maybe you could try to remove the `node_modules` and `.angular` folder and try installing again. Or checking out the git repo again to start with a clean project.

Comment: Anyway this is not the updated code, but i was try to clone the code from here, and run. But the result is the same

Comment: But is this repo working fine for you as well?

Comment: @Torben its running now, but its still have problem with the red line like the picture

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Torben, thank you the project already running well now. I did your suggest, and it just work today. And thank you for all of you guys for help me. I'm beginner so I keep learn more and more.